# JS Google+ Retrieve Circles List

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-plus

I'm trying to request the URL to get Circles List for user in an app using JavaScript: 
my code is

```
var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.media.upload',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profiles.read',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/paymentssandbox.make_payments',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full'];



function getCircles() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/circles?access_token=' + access_token,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```

and I turned on permissions in my app
Google+ API 
Google+ Domains API

But this request retrieved

```
error
    Object { errors=[1], code=403, message="Forbidden"}

code
    403

errors
    [Object { domain="global", reason="forbidden", message="Forbidden"}]

0
    Object { domain="global", reason="forbidden", message="Forbidden"}

domain
    "global"

message
    "Forbidden"

reason
    "forbidden"

message     "Forbidden"
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `access_token` actually contains a valid access token at this point?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are authenticating a Google Apps (@example.com) account and not a Google (@gmail.com) account?

Comment: I checked my access_token and it returned valid value
How could I authenticate my app

Comment: I think Abraham identified the issue: [the Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) is only "for people who use Google Apps at college, at work, or at home." It appears that Google does not currently allow apps to list circles for regular Google+ accounts.